# Adding custom field in default joomla 3.4 registration form

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4

Recently I have stumbled upon a situation in Joomla 3.4 where I need to add a custom field attached with default registration form.

I surfed the existing resources which say that I should navigate to joomla_root/components/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml and then change the file accordingly.

I have done that but nothing is showing up. By changing code in xml files its shows the chagnes on front end and back end as well but problem is this that were to write its php code. Thank you

Comment: How to add custom fields? Where to add the variable name in registration.php (register function)

Comment: In the administrator go to extensions/plugins, filter by type and choose "user", then find the "Profile" and open it. Check out the options on the right handside, enable the plugin.

Comment: It not works , not fix my problem.

Comment: but why?? aslo **DO NOT** modify the profile plugin or com_users files, this is Joomla core and will be overwritten when you next upgrade.

Comment: so then how to over come the issue ?

Comment: @Shehryar - Did you ever resolve this issue? If not I can give you some input on what you need to do to create a custom profile field plugin.